# Collecting threads in Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, oop, qt

I am looking for a way to get all threads created by one of my class to let me use them (threads are created dynamically depending on the user and I can't predict how many will be working while my application is working). Is there a good way to get all thread objects pointers and put them in one place so I can manipulate those threads?

Comment: Why would you want to "predict"? If it is your class creating the threads, what do you have to predict?

Comment: Well, I meant I cannot predict how many threads will be created. I just want to put them somewhere to let me work with them. I need to update the list of active threads and remove from the list threads that are no longer active.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a first, the best solution would definitely to keep track of the `QThread`'s created. Even if they are created "on-the-fly", you should be able to store pointer to them, even globally.

Assuming they are at least parented to the same `QObject`, you could use:

```
QList<QThread*> QObject::findChildren <QThread*> () const
```

To find all child `QThread`'s

Comment: Yes, they are parented and this is the solution I was looking for. Thank you!